# going through TextBox of UserForm

Tags: vba, userform

what would be an elegant way to avoid 4 individual macros for 4 TextBoxes in one userform?

```
Private Sub txt1_Change()
If txt1 = "" Then
txt1.BackColor = vbRed
Else
txt1.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub
Private Sub txt2_Change()
If txt2 = "" Then
txt2.BackColor = vbRed
Else
txt2.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt3_Change()
If txt3 = "" Then
txt3.BackColor = vbRed
Else
txt3.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt4_Change()
If txt4 = "" Then
txt4.BackColor = vbRed
Else
txt4.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub
```

what would be an elegant way to avoid 4 individual macros for 4 TextBoxes in one userform?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with this arrangement:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub txtx_Change(ByVal txtx As Object)
  If txtx = "" Then
    txtx.BackColor = vbRed
  Else
    txtx.BackColor = vbWhite
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt1_Change()
  txtx_Change txt1
End Sub

Private Sub txt2_Change()
  txtx_Change txt2
End Sub

Private Sub txt3_Change()
  txtx_Change txt3
End Sub

Private Sub txt4_Change()
  txtx_Change txt4
End Sub
```

`txtx_Change()` passes an argument as the active textbox object.

Comment: thanks, I will try it. I think I won't play with class module etc, it's only 4 textboxes so really no nead to "over code" I guess. Thank you